# Echo custom options with the values for Magento

Tags: php, magento

How to echo all custom options with all the values by product id for Magento?

If i am using this code...

```
 public function ws_productdetail($store_id, $service, $productid) 
 {      

 $res=array();

  $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productid))
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $all_product_images = array();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);

 foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $all_product_images[] = $image->getUrl();
             }

   foreach($productsCollection as $product) 
    {

      $res["id"] = $product->getId();
      $res["name"] = $product->getName();
      $res["price"] = number_format($product->getPrice(),2);

     }
     return($res); 
      }
```

... how can I get the custom options?

For example say for a product JEANS, COLOR with various values {blue,black,brown} and every option will have different prices, then how i get all this information as output.

Comment: `Please help me` . How to help you without any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to show the all DROPDOWN custom option on view page then try this.

```
         $productid = $_product->getId(); //PLEASE ENTER THE PRODUCT ID HERE

         $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productid);

         $attVal = $product->getOptions();

         $optStr = "";

        foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal)
          {

          $optStr.='<dl><div class="custom_select_css">
           <dt><label>'.$optionVal->getTitle().'</label></dt>
           <dd class="last">
           <div class="input-box">';

          $optStr.= "<select id='".$optionVal->getId()."' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";

           foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal)
           {

             $price = number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0);
             $optStr.= "<option price='".number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0)."' data-label='".$colorarray[$valuesVal->getTitle()]."' value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle(); if($price != '0'){$optStr.=" +$".number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),2);}$optStr.="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>";

           }

             $optStr.= "</select></div></dd><div></dl>";
           }

           echo $optStr;
```

**------------------------------ UPDATED CODE -------------------------------**

```
public function ws_customdetail ($productid) 
{      
    $all_custom_option_array = array();

    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productid);

    $attVal = $product->getOptions();

    $optStr = "";

    $inc=0;
    foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal)
      {

         $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_name']=$optionVal->getTitle();
         $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_id']=$optionVal->getId();


         $inner_inc =0;
         foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal)
             {

                $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'][$inner_inc]['title'] = $valuesVal->getTitle();
                $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'][$inner_inc]['price'] = number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0);

               $inner_inc++;
             }

         $inc++;
       }

       return $all_custom_option_array;
 }
```

Use ws_customdetail function and pass the product id in it.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY. BUT I WANTED THE CHECKBOX VALUES IN AN ARRAY LIKE THIS. FOR ANY PRODUCT: {"id":"3","name":"Jeans","price":"50.00","tax":"5.00"}]);

Comment: do you want me to add the custom option code in this ws_productdetail function ?

Comment: I want another ws_customdetail function in which i have to get the custom option values in the form of an array.

Comment: Returning nothing. Its blank

Comment: are you passing product id in it ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the SAMICOLUMN ( ; ) , just after this line $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'] so please add the samicolumn and then check

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS THE EXACT CODE THAT WORKED FOR ME.**

```
public function customdetail($productid){      
$all_custom_option_array = array();
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productid);
$attVal = $product->getOptions();
$optStr = "";
$inc=0;
foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal){
     $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_name']=$optionVal->getTitle();
     $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_id']=$optionVal->getId();
     $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_type']=$optionVal->getType();
     $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'];
     $inner_inc =0;
     foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal){
            $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'][$inner_inc]['title'] = $valuesVal->getTitle();
            $all_custom_option_array[$inc]['custom_option_value_array'][$inner_inc]['price'] = number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0);
            $inner_inc++;}
     $inc++;}
   return $all_custom_option_array;}
```

HOPE THIS WILL HELP SOMEONE :)

THANX